# Solr: facets when joining over multiple cores

Tags: solr, facet

I am using the cross-core joining function of Solr (4.9) like this:

`q={!join from=id to=referenceId fromIndex=otherCore}fieldInOtherCore:value`

Is there a way to provide facets for this query based on fields from the "otherCore"?

- Fields in main core: id, referenceId etc.
- Fields in other core: id, fieldInOtherCore, someFacetField etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not at the current time (4.9) at least. The resulting document set will only contain fields values from the main core.

> Fields or other properties of the documents being joined "from" are
>   not available for use in processing of the resulting set of "to"
>   documents

This is also indicated in [the join quick start example](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/Join):

> Notice the results are of the manufacturers who make those items and
>   not of the products themselves even though the match is on the
>   products